# how to compare complex decimal number with integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm going to get all clinics that are near to my latitude and longitude. i did that with following method. the result of dist is a long value that i need to compare it with a integer value. i don't know why i get this error during the compare dist and distance which is a integer value.
this is my error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<=' for (-2.693846638591123+0.0i):Complex):
```

and this is what everyhting that i did for this:

```
  def get_clinic_list
     ulat=params[:lat]
     ulang=params[:lang]
     distance=params[:distance]
     @clinic=[]
     Clinic.all.each do |clinic|
       if clinic_distance(ulat,ulang,distance,clinic.id)
         @doctor=DoctorProfile.find_by(user_id: clinic.user_id)
       end
     end
  end
  def clinic_distance(ulat, ulang,distance,clinic)
     @clinic=Clinic.find(clinic)
     diff_lat= ulat.to_f - @clinic.latitude.to_f
     diff_lang= ulang.to_f - @clinic.longitude.to_f
     #disc=Math.sqrt(((diff_lat*119.574)**2)+(diff_lang * Math.cos(diff_lat) * 111.320))
     a=(diff_lat * 119.574) ** 2
     b= diff_lang * Math.cos(diff_lat) * 111.320
     c=a+b
     logger.info "the c parameter is #{c}"

     dist=Math.sqrt(c)

     dist = dist ** 2
     if dist <= distance
         return true
     else
         return false
     end
  end
```

Comment: it's a formula, it is the Globular of the earth

Comment: i think the ruby doesnt have any problem with all kind of arithmetics

Comment: Your `clinic_distance` method is *completely* wrong. `119.574` comes out of nowhere. `b` should be squared. You calculate `dist` as the square of a square root. Your `if` statement doesn't do anything, it just returns `dist <= distance`

Comment: @mudasobwa _"`Math.cos` returning `Complex` value"_ – [`Math.cos`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Math.html#method-c-cos) returns a `Float`. [`CMath.cos`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/cmath/rdoc/CMath.html#method-c-cos) returns a `Complex` number if the argument is a `Complex` number.

Comment: @Stefan shame on me :( No idea how it ever came to my mind.

Comment: @Stefan: `Math.cos` can return a `Complex` number if the argument has an imaginary part and `'mathn'` has been required. The `Complex` value possibly comes from a negative `c`. It would still require 'mathn', though. Anyway, I hope this code doesn't go in production, ever.

Comment: @EricDuminil well, yes, kind of. `mathn` [replaces](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_1/lib/mathn.rb#L54) `Math` with `CMath`, so you actually invoke `CMath.cos`. It's quite a hack and `mathn` will be removed from stdlib in Ruby 2.5.

Comment: @Stefan: Didn't know that, thanks. Could the complex numbers comes from the DB?

Comment: @EricDuminil I have no clue, but that would be quite unusual. I never had to deal with complex numbers when doing lat-long calculations. Floats worked fine for me so far ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: I guess you could use `longitude + latitude * i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex numbers don't support `<=` or `>=` (although they do support `==`)

Simplest solution is to get the absolute part of the number

```
if dist.abs <= distance
```

Comment: I did that but i get error that can not convert to float

Comment: in fact i get this error:  RangeError (can't convert -2.693846638591123+0.0i into Float)

Comment: ok, hm, it looks like the imaginary part is zero, so I'm surprised.  Try using "abs" as per my revised answer?

Comment: OP's method is completely wrong. `.abs` isn't enough to repair it. :-/

Comment: Thanks, @EricDuminil  .... I think answering the specific question of how to compare a complex number to an integer, my answer solves that for others in future who're searching for a similar answer.  If or when OP notes he's not getting what he needs out of the method, he'll likely look at your answer, hopefully.

Comment: The answer to "How to compare a complex number to an integer?" is: ["You don't"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Ordering).

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake is pretty much every line of your `clinic_distance` method. I tried my best at correcting it, but I cannot test it without your data.

The problem isn't about `Complex` numbers. I don't know where this `Complex` number comes from, possibly from a negative `c` in your `Math.sqrt(c)`.

```
EarthRadius = 6371 # km
OneDegree = EarthRadius * 2 * Math::PI / 360 # 1° latitude in km

def get_clinic_list
  lat = params[:lat]
  lon = params[:lang] # :lang???
  max_distance = params[:distance] # :distance should probably be :max_distance
  @clinic = [] # What do you do with this empty array?
  Clinic.all.each do |clinic|
    if distance_in_km(lat, lon, clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude) < max_distance
      # Do you really want to keep overriding @doctor every time a clinic is found?
      @doctor = DoctorProfile.find_by(user_id: clinic.user_id)
    end
  end
  # You return every clinic, even ones far away...
end

def distance_in_km(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
  diff_lat = lat1.to_f - lat2.to_f
  diff_lon = lon1.to_f - lon2.to_f

  lat_km = diff_lat * OneDegree
  lon_km = diff_lon * OneDegree * Math.cos(lat1.to_f * Math::PI / 180) # Math.cos expects a radian angle

  Math.sqrt(lat_km**2 + lon_km**2)
end
```